# Angular.js - Pass and array from one contoller to another and update it

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework, controllers

I am trying to pass a scope array from on controller and then update it in the next one by adding a group to the array
im having problems the because i am trying to create a group list and when you click the add button it will take you to the newgroup templates where you can add another group to that array

```
    .controller("GroupsController", function($scope,$stateParams,$state){
        $scope.groups=[];
       $scope.newGroup=function(){
          $state.go("newgroup");
       };
       $scope.groups.push($stateParams.groupname);
        $scope.groupChat = function(group){
         $state.go("chat",{groupname:group,firstname:$stateParams.firstname, lastname:    $stateParams.lastname})
       }
     })

    .controller("NewGroupController",function($scope,$state){
        $scope.createGroup = function(groupname){
            $state.go("groups",{groupname: groupname})
        }
   })
```

the problem is everytime it returns to the groups template it makes $scope.groups empty again and then add the latest group to the array but remove all the others

I want it to add the new groups to the array but keep the old ones as well

Answer (score 1):

User service to share the data from one controller to another controller.
Reference:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

You can just inject this service in both controller. Before navigating to another controller assign the value and send.

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
  this.sharingArray=[];
});
```